# std::is_same<A,B>::value == true in line 1, false in line 2

Tags: c++, templates

I have a code that returns true in one line, false in the other.

For example,

```
struct Z{
    static const int value = 10;
};

struct A : Z{
};
struct B : Z{
};

int main(){
    if(std::is_same<A,B>::value){
        static_assert(std::is_same<A,B>::value , "why am i here?");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why it throws a static assert error?

Comment: Because `A` and `B` are not the same.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert

Comment: The "if" controls runtime flow.  If you want the to only check at runtime, then don't use a static assert, but an ordinary runtime assert.  A static_assert is tested as soon as it's compiled, and if its condition isn't true, your compile fails.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `static_assert` is a static (that is: compile time) assert. It does not care about the `if` statement (evaluated at run-time) above.